# jQPlot : Set Y Axis numbers

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jqplot

I am building charts using primefaces. I searched and got to know that primefaces uses jQuery plugin called jQPlot for plotting graphs.

My problem is when I am generating line charts, It is showing Y Axis number as 20163,15122 etc.I want those number like 20000,15000

Chart Extender  Code is :

```
function single_line_charts() {
            this.cfg.axesDefaults = {
                labelRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
            };
            this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
                rendererOptions : {
                    smooth : false
                }
            }
            this.cfg.highlighter = {
                sizeAdjust : 7.5
            };
            this.cfg.legend = {
                renderer : $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
                show : false,
                show : true,
                location : 'n',
                placement : 'outsideGrid',
                rendererOptions : {
                    numberRows : 1,
                    numberColumns : 1,
                    seriesToggle : false,
                    disableIEFading : true
                }
            };
            this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
                formatString : '%d'
            };
        }
```

Is is possible to set y axis values?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Within jqPlot Options you can set the yaxis min and max values as well as the tickSpacing as in:

```
axes: {
  yaxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 30000,
    tickSpacing: 5000
}
```

You can find the details here [jqplot-axis.tickSpacing](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.tickSpacing)

I hope it works for you.